# How to configure WSO2 store console to visible only one environment( either production tab or Sandbox tab but both)?

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

WSO2 end user is getting confused with store console with production and sandbox tabs as we have separate setup for Production and sandbox.
He needs see only production tab in production environment.

Comment: This you have to do only for specific user or for across the environment ?

Comment: not specific user ,it must be across environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sreekanth
To do this you need customize the API store, creating a new subtheme to be able to hide elements in interface.
Follow the steps provided in [1].
Hope this helps you.
[1] https://medium.com/@kosalasananthana/how-to-modify-ui-elements-in-wso2-api-manager-store-2c10af074eea

Comment: Hello, same process it's used to customize both store and publisher interface: create a subtheme and put inside only the files you need to be changed.